# one's vs ones; and omission of "the" with superlatives

Tags: homophones

Source: My Aussie teacher

> They are the one's nearest and dearest in my life.

Shouldn't it be without an apostrophe: "the ones?"  Because it should be plural(they).
And is it ok that we omit "the" in the superlatives("nearest" and "dearest")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to be

> **the ones**

since it is a ***specific*** group of people and this is the usual ***pattern*** for expressing this.

**Edit**

I just reread the question.  Thing is that BrE and its derivations, AusE included, do funny things with the determinant "**the**". For example

> He is in **the** hospital. *(AmE)*
>   He is in hospital. *(BrE)*
>
> In **the** future, we should avoid bad weather. *(AmE)*
>   In future, we should avoid bad weather. *(BrE)*

To me, it's part the cultural differences between AmE and BrE, AmE tends to err on the side of specificity.

Comment: Yes, for me it's also so obvious and usual I wonder why my native English teacher denies it

Comment: Ask her for an explanation.

Comment: Sorry, I still do not understand, "should we use the article "the" before "nearest" or not?

Comment: It's a matter of style "They are nearest and dearest in my life" = "They are ***the*** nearest and dearest in my life", both have the same meaning.